# confusion about the difference between series and dataframe(pandas)

Tags: pandas

For pandas in python, does series has to be multiple columns or one column? If I do dataframe[[column1, column2]], it will return a dataframe or series? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs on Stack Overflow. Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 0):

A series has to be one and only one column. A dataframe can be just one column but most of the time it's going to have more than that. In your example, the result will be a dataframe. Dataframes are signified by double square brackets:

```
dataframe[[column1,column2]]
```

while Series are signified by single square brackets:

```
dataframe[column1]
```

If you try to get a series with more than one column:

```
dataframe[column1,column2]
```

you will get an error message because series can't be made up of multiple columns. However,

```
dataframe[[column1]]
```

will work because dataframes can have one or many columns.

I really recommend using the type function.

```
type(dataframe[column1])
```

tells you what the object is.